# Read binary file from a zip file from C# without unzipping it

Tags: c#, .net, zip, bin, binaryreader

I would like to read a binary file from a zip file without unzipping it .

The zip file structure:

```
zipFolderName/subFolder/BinFile
```

In the BinFile, I have:

```
Id1, id2, value1 // id1, id2 are string, value1 is int
```

In C#:

```
 ZipEntry binFileName = …; // it has been got from zipFile entries
 MemoryStream ms  = new MemoryStream();
 binFileName.Extract(ms);

using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(ms))
{
    string id1 = reader.ReadString(); // error popped here
    string id2 = reader.ReadString();
    int value1 = reader.ReadInt32();
}
```

I got error: 
    Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.
It seems that BinaryReader cannnot read MemoryStream  ?

Comment: Did you try seeking to the start of the memory stream before trying to read from it?

Comment: Note that BinaryReader.ReadString does expect that the string length prefixes the string in the stream in a certain data format. If this string length data is not there, the method will misinterpret the byte data in the stream and behave funny...

Comment: A memory stream has only one position (unlike unix which has both a read and write poistion).  So when you write to a memory stream the position is left at the end of the stream.  So before you read you must set the poisition back to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `binFileName.Extract(ms);` try the following:

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```